# How to make ffmpeg preserve transparency?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

We know `ffmpeg` can help us with overlaying image on video. My target is to wrap a video with an image whose background is `transparent`.

```
ffmpeg -i device/nexus5_portrait.png -i device/input.mp4\
-filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,0,5)'"\
-b:v 16M -bufsize 16M device/output.mp4;
```

**Output.mp4 has a black background. So is there any way to preserve the `alpha` channel?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new idea saves me.

- Use `ffmpeg` caonver `input.mp4` to `input.gif`
- Use `ImageMagick` to `overlay` `input.gif` on `nexus5_portrait.png`.

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b:v 16M input.gif
  magick image.png null: \( input.gif -coalesce \) -gravity Center -layers composite des.gif
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a video codec that supports transparency. By default, mp4 uses H.264 (using x264) which doesn't support alpha. You could look at VP8 or VP9, which [do support alpha](http://wiki.webmproject.org/alpha-channel). You could also (if compression is less critical) use an image codec which supports alpha (e.g. PNG) instead of a video codec (-c:v png) for the output.

Comment: Now my idea is that first convert input.mp4 to gif then wrap the gif with png

Answer (score 0):

ffv1 is a great format for video processing, it's lossless and preserves alpha channel. You can overlay to ffv1 and then convert to h264. It's a relatively fast codec, the only drawback is that temporary file will be very large. This format also gives you frame accuracy when cutting.
More info here:
[lossless-video-codec-supporting-alpha-channels](https://superuser.com/questions/1505679/lossless-video-codec-supporting-alpha-channels)